# Normal distribution Questioning

Tags: statistics

The weights of a group of children are approximately normally distributed with mean 15kg and standard deviation=1.75 kg 
What proportion of the children will weigh 13 of or more?

Can someone help me solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Let $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(15,1.75^{2})$ be a normal distributed random variable with mean $15$ and variance $1.75^{2}$. Then you have to compute

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(Y \geq 13) &= \mathbb{P}(\frac{Y - 15}{1.75} \geq -\frac{8}{7})\\
&= 1 - \Phi(-\frac{8}{7})\\
&= 1 - (1 - \Phi(\frac{8}{7}))\\
&= \Phi(\frac{8}{7})\\
&\approx 0.87345
\end{align}
where $\Phi$ is the Cumulative distribution function of the Standard normal random variable with mean $0$ and variance $1$.